# Is it necessary to put templates into a map for reusing in Go?

Tags: go

To deal with every request in a web application, the normal code about templates is like this:

```
t:= template.New("welcome")
t, _ = t.ParseFiles("welcome.tpl")
t.Execute(w, data)
```

I guess `ParseFiles` every time cost a lot. Is it possible to reuse the template? So I improved  it like this:

```
//templateMap := make(map[string][template])
//...
tplName :="welcome"
t := templateMap[tplName]
if t=nil{
    t:= template.New(tplName )
    t, _ = t.ParseFiles("welcome.tpl")
    templateMap[tplName] = t
}

t.Execute(w, data)
```

I wonder it is feasible or practicable to improve efficiency by  putting templates into a map or a cache?
I also wonder the function  `Execute` is thread safe or not?

`func (t *Template) Execute(wr io.Writer, data interface{}) (err error)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A template can actually act as a map of templates by itself. Here's what I do:

I declare a global template variable:

```
var t = template.New("master")
```

I don't actually use the "master" template, except as a container for other templates.

Then, I load all the templates when my app starts:

```
func init() {
    _, err := t.ParseGlob("templates/*.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Error loading templates:", err)
    }
}
```

Then when I want to use one of the templates, I ask for it by name:

```
t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "user.html", data)
```

Comment: Is there a convenient way to make this approach work with templates that use inheritance? (E.g., where there is a base template for some of the templates?)

Answer (score 0):

From the source code of template.go, the Execute function use a Lock, I'm a newbie, it looks is thread safe, but might not efficiency if put the template instance to a map and try to reuse it, if you need to serve lots of concurrent requests:

```
func (t *Template) Execute(wr io.Writer, data interface{}) (err error) {
        t.nameSpace.mu.Lock()
        if !t.escaped {
                if err = escapeTemplates(t, t.Name()); err != nil {
                        t.escaped = true
                }
        }
        t.nameSpace.mu.Unlock()
        if err != nil {
                return
        }
        return t.text.Execute(wr, data)
}
```

Comment: Presumably the expensive part is the Execute call at the end.  The critical section is doing one-off initialisation for the template, so shouldn't be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a closure if the template has a 1-to-1 relationship with the handler. The benefit is the template is only executed once and does not require a global variable, but the downside is the template can only be used within the handler where it was declared.

```
func templateHandler() http.HandlerFunc {

    // template is executed once
    tmp := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("welcome.html"))

    // return our handler with the template available through the closure
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // ...perform other handler work ...
        // execute template against data
        tmp.Execute(w, myData)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/gopher", templateHandler())
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```