# Golang global variable of type html/template not defined in other packages

Tags: go

I have declared a global var as suggested in this question [Is it necessary to put templates into a map for reusing in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352130/is-it-necessary-to-put-templates-into-a-map-for-reusing-in-go)

I declared the global var in my main package before `func main()` but it is still not declared in another package.

```
package main

import{
  "html/template"
  .....
)

var tmpl = template.New("master")

func main() {

    func init() {

        _, err := tmpl.ParseGlob("templates/*.html")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln("Error loading templates:", err)
        }
....
}
```

In another package I write inside a function:

```
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "venue-index.html", res)
```

but I get an error

> tmpl: undefined

I realise that there are other similar questions but the answers have not solved my problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no such thing as a global variable in Go. Only package variables.

Comment: A better approach, though, is dependency injection. Pass your variable into the function(s) that need it, rather than relying on global state. Global state is (usually) evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tmpl` will not be visible from another package. To import variables from other packages you have to refer to them by a fully qualified name and have the variables start with an uppercase letter, `pack.Tmpl` etc.

Also it's impossible to import variables from `main` into other packages.

Comment: @markhorrocks: yes, a helper package makes sense if it's being used from more than one package

Comment: It's not highly unusual, it's impossible. You cannot import `main` from another package. It's a hard compiler rule, but even if it weren't it would still be impossible - `main` is the entry point of every application, so any reachable package importing `main` would be creating a circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I used for declaring templates in a helper package:

```
package helpers

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
)

// Tmpl global template var
var Tmpl = template.New("master")

func init() {
    _, err := Tmpl.ParseGlob("templates/*.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Error loading templates:", err)
    }
}
```

Then in my controllers package:

```
package controllers

import (
        "myapp/helpers"
)

someFunc() {
.... 
helpers.Tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "header.html", nil)
....
}
```